# PC hotspot unable to connect with Android device

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, android, hotspot, connectify

I want to share my laptop wifi with my phone.

**I used many ways to make a hotspot(cmmd prmpt and multiple sw's) and did make them , but the phone never connects to any of them , and always stops at "obtaining IP address" .**

If I set IP to static , it connects but doesnt work.

I used to think it was my Anti-virus (ESET) which was blocking the access through firewall , but the problem persists even after removing the antivirus

Can it be that it left some settings behind?

**PS:

- **I have enabled firewall and allowed the network(hotspot sw) to
  function**
- **I have tried connecting after disabling the firewall , still no
  change.**
- **I have tried to reset the firewall settings**
- **I have allowed the sharing of connection in adapter properties.**

I am now clueless. please Help if you can

Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the sharing page in adapter properties.

Comment: i added it. Is this what you asked for? the details are of the hotspot adapter.

Comment: That's useful, but not what we need. Right click on the WiFi adapter and click on the Sharing tab.

Comment: I am using a softwre called Baidu. I tried connectify and making one from cmmd prompt but it didnt work. this one worked for my friend.

Comment: so I guess no one here knows it....

Comment: It's possible your wireless card is simply not capable of working in this mode.

Comment: No , that's not it. I have friends who have the same cards , and it works for them. It has to do with some advanced-firewall settings ,which ESET AV configured when it was installed.

Comment: I assumed when you said you've tried disabling and resetting the firewall that you actually succeeded in doing just that. If not, I suggest doing a Winsock reset: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx

Comment: What version of Windows do you have? In Windows 10, making a mobile hotspot is a builtin feature.